# How to determine loggedin users for Remote Web Workplace on SBS2003

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-sbs-2003

We have SBS2003 and I would like to know which users are currently logged in remotely through RWW. If possible, it would be nice to know what machines they have remoted into as well. Besides active connections, is there a way to see historical connections in some kind of log file?

So can the above be done? If so, how? Does Microsoft make it easier to see/track in TSG in Win2008?

Answer (score 3):

In 2008, you can see who is logged into RWW by typing in the command prompt `net sess` but I am not sure if it will work in 2003 as I can't try it.

I also happened to find some interesting information about a user who figured out how to [track users via the event logs](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Windows/microsoft.public.windows.server.sbs/2006-02/msg01416.html)